# TraceId from de.siegmar.logbackgelf.GelfUdpAppender to graylog

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, graylog, gelf

I am using **de.siegmar.logbackgelf.GelfUdpAppender** from pushing logs to graylog but TraceId is not coming into graylog.

Has tried with putting

```
<staticField>logging_correlation_id:%X{X-B3-TraceId:-}</staticField>
```

but instead of tracId, **%X{X-B3-TraceId:-}** is printing.